# Does an ex-slave need to do Tshuva?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, slave-serve-eved-avadim

[Rashi, on Shemot 21:6 that talks about an Eved-Ivri extending his servitude, writes](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.21.6?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.21.6.3&lang2=bi):

> What is the reason that the ear had to be pierced rather than any other limb of the servant’s body? Rabban Jochanan ben Zaccai said: That ear which heard on Mount Sinai, (Exodus 20:13) “Thou shalt not steal” and yet its owner went and stole and was therefore sold as a slave — let it be pierced! Or, in the case of him who sold himself from destitution, having committed no theft, the reason is: That ear which heard on Mount Sinai what I said, (Leviticus 25:55) “For unto Me the children Israel are servants” and yet its owner went and procured for himself another master — let it be pierced! (Mekhilta d'Rabbi Yishmael 21:6:3; Kiddushin 22b). Rabbi Simeon interpreted this verse like a jewel (i. e. giving it an ethical signification): In what respect are door and doorpost different from all other objects in the house that they should be singled out for this purpose? God, in effect, said: door and doorpost that were eye-witnesses in Egypt when I passed over the lintel and the two doorposts, freeing Israel from slavery, and when I said, (Leviticus 25:55) “For unto Me the children of Israel are servants” — servants to Me but not servants of servants (of human beings), and yet this man went and procured another master for himself — let him be pieced in their presence (i. e. let them be eye-witnesses now when this man voluntarily prolongs his state of slavery)! (Kiddushin 22b.)

And then on the same verse writes:

> AND HE SHALL SERVE HIM FOR EVER — This means until the Jubilee.

Given that lengthening one's servitude was greatly frowned upon, so much so that it seems to be a transgression of the whole concept of "Eved Hashem", would such a slave, once freed by the Yovel, need to do Tshuva on this? And if yes, would this require a korban?

Comment: Even an explicit biblical prohibition doesn't typically require a korban if there is no *karet* attached. Also, one can do "teshuva" even for things that are not actually prohibited, but are less than ideal.

Comment: @Loewian why not write it as an answer?